# How to get string between two commands in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to write a vim script for get string between two commands. eg:
`\string{new strings}`, I want to get the new string if it contain empty lines or space

```
:%s/\\string{[^}]*\n*[^}]*}/new/gec
```

Comment: Not very clear what you want. Could you please show some examples of what you want to match in an input?

Comment: select the contents inside the curly brace of \string{} even if there is any
space or line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement is not that clear, but if you want to

> get the "new string" if it contain empty lines or space

Also you commented:

> select the contents inside the curly brace of \string{} **even if** there is any space or line

This line does it, it is a search command, not `:s`

```
/\\string{\zs\_[^}]*
```

If you want to do some substitution on the content between `\string{` and `}`, you can use the pattern:

```
%s/\\string{\zs\_[^}]*\ze}/whatever/g
```

Note that, you can also write `s/\\string{\zs\_[^}]*/whatever/g`,  the `\ze}` will make sure that the closing bracket must be there. Not sure if this is needed.

For the detail of `\_[]`, do a `:h \_[`

Comment: Your search command also matches "\string{string}", which contains no space or newline.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis so the requirement is **only if**?

Comment: That's not for me to answer.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
%s/\\string{[^}]*\n*[^}]*\n*[^}]*\n*[^}]*\n*[^}]*\n*[^}]*\n*[^}]*\n*[^}]*\n*[^}]*\n*[^}]*\n*[^}]*\n*[^}]*\n*[^}]*\n*[^}]*\n*[^}]*\n*[^}]*\n*[^}]*\n*[^}]*\n*[^}]
*}/new/gec
```

Comment: yes! i knew,  but learned a new code, thanks for that. if the search sentence contains a couple of braces inside, then there any way to search, for example: \string{new new {string} strings}. i need "new new {string} strings"

Comment: I think you can then make use of the "greedy" feature, just match `.*}`

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Comment: ok, if the sentence is: \string{new new {string} strings} new {string}, is there any way to get the output like "new new {string} strings" (only required the contents of the corresponding braces)